# :How to change `Prefix :` (command prompt) to `Prefix ;` in tmux?

Tags: tmux, terminal-multiplexer

I tried to change from  `prefix - :` to `prefix - ;` in tmux and it doesn't seem to work.

Edit 1:

Explanation

For a tmux prompt you hit, `prefix` then `:` (*i.e* `shift` + `;`).
I want to change it to , `prefix` then `;` (*i.e* just `;`).

Comment: I'm... not sure what the question is here? Plus, you seem to indicate that you've already found the answer...

Answer (score 1):

I  figured it out with help from [Orlandocollins](https://www.reddit.com/user/Orlandocollins)

add this to your .tmux.conf and switch the key bindings.

```
# tmux prompt key 
unbind ';'
unbind ':'
bind-key ';' command-prompt
bind-key : last-pane
```